# Using variation principle on quantum oscillator with general potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

Consider a general bounding potential $V(x)$. The hamiltonian is $$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x).$$ We want to apply the variation principle in equation $$F\leq F_0+\langle H-H_0\rangle_0.$$ $\langle\rangle_0$ means the average taken in a system characterized by $H_0$ and $F$ is Helmholtz free energy.
Our trial Hamiltonian is $$H_0=\frac{p^2}{2m_0} + \frac{m_0\omega_0^2}{2}(x - a)^2$$ which is just a Hamiltonian of a harmonic oscillator with its equilibrium moved by $a$.
Now we need to vary $a$, $m_0$, and $\omega_0$ to show that $m_0=m$ and that $\omega_0$ and $a$ are determined from $$\langle V'(x)\rangle_0=0$$ and $$\langle xV'(x)\rangle_0=\langle \frac{p^2}{m}\rangle_0.$$

The way I understand it is that I have to differentiate $\langle H-H_0\rangle_0$ with respect to $a$, $m_0$, and $\omega_0$ and set those expressions to zero. When I do that I get these:

With respect to $a$ $$\langle x\rangle_0=a$$
With respect to $m_0$ $$-\frac{\omega_0^2}{2}\langle (x-a)^2\rangle_0+\frac{\langle p^2\rangle_0}{2m_0^2}=0$$
$$m_0^2=\frac{\langle p^2\rangle_0}{\langle (x-a)^2\rangle_0\omega_0^2}.$$
With respect to $\omega_0$ $$m_0\omega_0\langle (x-a)^2\rangle_0=0$$
$$\omega_0=0$$

Neither of these seems to prove what I'm supposed to show. Did I misunderstood the problem or have I made a mistake that I'm not seeing? How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to differentiate $F_0+\langle H-H_0\rangle$ not just the energy part. Note that in this case, $F_0$ depends only on $\omega_0$ so it won't actually change the result for the variation of $a,m$. How did you get your three derivatives ? From the $\langle H\rangle_0$ term, you should have a remaining $V$ dependence.

Comment: I thought that since $V$ depends only on $x$ the derivatives should be zero.

Comment: What is $F$?...

Comment: Helmholtz free energy

Comment: No, since you are taking the average over the ansatz ensemble, $\langle V\rangle_0$ depends on $a,\omega_0,m_0$.